# How to add multiple drop down select tags side by side

Tags: html, css

I have implemented 2 select tags with values but when i executed they are not showing side by side as shown in the result below.

But i want to implement those select tags side by side like should i use `margin-top:20px;`  or any other way to do this 
[image: This]

```html
<!doctype html>


    
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>



        <div id="example" role="application">
      <div id="select" class="demo-section k-content">
           
            <h4 style="margin-top: 2em;">select</h4>
            <select id="size" placeholder="Select size..." style="width: 300px;" >
              <option />easy 
              <option />to
              <option />code
              <option />way
              <option />always
              <option />easily
            </select>
     
            
        </div>
        
<div id="example1" role="application">
      <div id="select" class="demo-section k-content">
           
            <h4 style="margin-top: 2em;">select</h4>
            <select id="size1" placeholder="Select size..." style="width: 300px;" >
              <option />C++
              <option />java
              <option />jquery
              <option />html
              <option />css
              <option />unix
            </select>
     
            
        </div>






            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    // create ComboBox from input HTML element
                    
                    // create ComboBox from select HTML element
                    $("#size").kendoComboBox();
 $("#size1").kendoComboBox();


                   
     var select = $("#size").data("kendoComboBox");
var select = $("#size1").data("kendoComboBox");



    
                });
            </script>
        </div>




</!doctype>
```

Comment: Put them both in the same `div`, or set `float: left` on the div elements. Also note that you have multiple errors in your HTML; ie. duplicate `id` attributes, missing closing tags, closing the wrong tags. Try running your code through an HTML validator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you need to wrap the `div id="select"` inside the `example` div. ( you were missing `</div>` closing tag of the `example` div )

then add style to the example divs

```
 <div id="example" role="application" style="float:left;width:49%; margin-right:2%">
 <div id="example1" role="application" style="float:left;width:49%;margin-right:0">
```

this way they will always stay side by side

see code snippet bellow. let me know if it helps

INFO : it's never a good idea to use duplicate `id`s in HTML , for example `<div id="select">` , and always recheck your html code ( closing tags, id-s etc. )

```html
<!doctype html>


    
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>



        <div id="example" role="application" style="float:left;width:49%; margin-right:2%">
      <div id="select" class="demo-section k-content">
           
            <h4 style="margin-top: 2em;">select</h4>
            <select id="size" placeholder="Select size..." style="width: 300px;" >
              <option />easy 
              <option />to
              <option />code
              <option />way
              <option />always
              <option />easily
            </select>
     
            
        </div>
</div>
        
<div id="example1" role="application" style="float:left;width:49%;margin-right:0">
      <div id="select" class="demo-section k-content">
           
            <h4 style="margin-top: 2em;">select</h4>
            <select id="size1" placeholder="Select size..." style="width: 300px;" >
              <option />C++
              <option />java
              <option />jquery
              <option />html
              <option />css
              <option />unix
            </select>
     
            
        </div>
 </div>





            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    // create ComboBox from input HTML element
                    
                    // create ComboBox from select HTML element
                    $("#size").kendoComboBox();
 $("#size1").kendoComboBox();


                   
     var select = $("#size").data("kendoComboBox");
var select = $("#size1").data("kendoComboBox");



    
                });
            </script>





</!doctype>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check after fullscreen

```html
<!doctype html>


    
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>



        <div id="example" role="application" style="width:100%;">
      <div id="select" class="demo-section k-content" style="float:left;">
           
            <h4 >select</h4>
            <select id="size" placeholder="Select size..." style="width: 300px;" >
              <option />easy 
              <option />to
              <option />code
              <option />way
              <option />always
              <option />easily
            </select>
     
            
  </div>
        

      <div id="select" class="demo-section k-content" style="float:left">
           
            <h4 >select</h4>
            <select id="size1" placeholder="Select size..." style="width: 300px;" >
              <option />C++
              <option />java
              <option />jquery
              <option />html
              <option />css
              <option />unix
            </select>
     
            
        </div>






            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    // create ComboBox from input HTML element
                    
                    // create ComboBox from select HTML element
                    $("#size").kendoComboBox();
 $("#size1").kendoComboBox();


                   
     var select = $("#size").data("kendoComboBox");
var select = $("#size1").data("kendoComboBox");



    
                });
            </script>
        </div>




</!doctype>
```